# regex substitution "." to "_"

Tags: r, regex, string, substitution

I have a specific issue with character substitution in strings:

If I have the following strings

```
"..A.B....c...A..D.."
"A..S.E.Q.......AW.."
".B.C..a...R......Ds"
```

Which regex substitution should I use to replace the dots and obtain the following strings:

```
"A_B_c_A_D"
"A_S_E_Q_AW"
"B_C_a_R_Ds"
```

I am using R.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you really need regex here? You can just iterate over characters and remove/replace symbols with simple rules

Comment: And what have you tried so far?  Why didn't it work?

Comment: Yes, the reason I want regex code for my issue is to avoid iterating or any other loop code

Comment: @Limey I tried firstly with gsub() but noticed that it was much more complex and that I would get more "_" than desired.

Comment: For a string `s`, `gsub('\\.*','_',s) `. You also stripped the leading and trailing characters so, `s %>% gsub('\\.*','_',.) %>% gsub('^_','',.) %>% gsub('_$','',.)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `stringr` from the ever fantastic `tidyverse`.

str1 <- "..A.B....c...A..D.."

```
str1 %>%
  #replace all dots that follow any word character ('\\.' escapes search, '+' matches one or more, '(?<=\\w)' followed by logic)
  str_replace_all('(?<=\\w)\\.+(?=\\w)', '_') %>%
  #delete remaining dots (i.e. at the start)
  str_remove_all('\\.')
```

As always plenty of ways to skin the cat with regex

Answer (score 1):

Here a solution using gsub in two parts

```
string = c("..A.B....c...A..D..","A..S.E.Q.......AW..",".B.C..a...R......Ds")
```

first remove start and end points

```
string2 = gsub("^\\.+|\\.+$", "", string)
```

finally replace one or more points with _

```
string2 = gsub("\\.+", "_", string2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using x shown in the Note at the end, use trimws to trim dot off both ends.  dot means any character so we have to escape it with backslashes to remove that meaning.  Then replace every dot with underscore using chartr.  No packages are used.

```
x |> trimws("both", "\\.") |> chartr(old = ".", new = "_")
## [1] "A_B____c___A__D"    "A__S_E_Q_______AW"  "B_C__a___R______Ds"
```

### Note

```
x <- c("..A.B....c...A..D..",
"A..S.E.Q.......AW..",
".B.C..a...R......Ds")
```